# how to reduce main.js and main.css and vendor.js divide in small chunk using webpack in react js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am working on performance optimization in react site last few days and I have read code-splitting documents using webpack. I have small knowledge about webpack bundling and code splitting. my webpack code.

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin; // eslint-disable-line prefer-destructuring
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin = require("duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin'); //gzip
const BrotliPlugin = require('brotli-webpack-plugin'); //brotli
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = require('config');

const webpackConfig = {
    mode: config.get('webpack.mode'),
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, config.get('webpack.output.path')),
        filename: `${config.get('webpack.output.scripts')}/[name].[hash:8].js`,
        chunkFilename: `${config.get('webpack.output.scripts')}/[name].[chunkhash:8].js`,
        publicPath: config.get('webpack.publicPath'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],

    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },

            { // config for sass compilation
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            { // config for images
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'images',
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
            { // config for fonts
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'fonts',
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },

        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        (config.get('webpack.mode') === 'production') ? new CleanWebpackPlugin([
            config.get('webpack.output.path'),
        ]) : () => {},
        (config.get('webpack.mode') === 'production') ? new DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin() : () => {},
        (config.get('webpack.mode') === 'production') ?(
            new CompressionPlugin({ //gzip plugin
                filename: '[path].gz[query]',
                algorithm: 'gzip',
                test: /\.(js|css|html|svg|txt|eot|otf|ttf|gif|png|jpg)$/,
                threshold: 8192,
                minRatio: 0.8
            }),
                new BrotliPlugin({ //brotli plugin
                    asset: '[path].br[query]',
                    test: /\.(js|css|html|svg|txt|eot|otf|ttf|gif|png|jpg)$/, //(js|css|html|svg|txt|eot|otf|ttf|gif)$/
                    threshold: 10240,
                    minRatio: 0.6
                }),
                new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                    patterns: [
                        { from: 'public' }
                    ]
                })

        ):()=>{},


        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: `${config.get('webpack.output.styles')}/[name].[chunkhash:8].css`,
            chunkFilename: `${config.get('webpack.output.styles')}/[name].[chunkhash:8].css`,
        }),
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: process.env.BA_MODE ? process.env.BA_MODE : 'disabled',
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    minSize: 0,
                    name: config.get('webpack.vendorsCodeSplitting') ? (module) => {
                        const re = /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/;
                        const packageName = module.context.match(re)[1];
                        return `vendors/pkg.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                    } : 'vendors',
                    priority: -10,
                },

                default: {
                    name: 'default',
                    minChunks: 2,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: -20,
                },
            },
        },
        minimizer: [
            (config.get('webpack.uglify')) ? new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: !!config.get('webpack.sourcemap'),
            }) : () => {},
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                    preset: [
                        'default', {
                            discardComments: {
                                removeAll: true,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    devtool: config.get('webpack.sourcemap'),
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        publicPath: config.get('webpack.publicPath'),
        open: config.get('webpack.open'),
        overlay: true,
    },
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong with webpack configuration to improve Google page insight speed index. I also attached a screenshot bundle analysis.[image: analysis]  many third-party libraries use on a home page its impacts on page speed? thank in advanced